# Save HTML tag from front end in mvc C# textbox

Tags: html, model-view-controller

I need to save  or  tab in textbox or textarea so user can see result in @HTml.Raw in Grid. In am able to see the result using @HTml.Raw but unable to save from front end but getting error from front end.
[image]

please see the error :-
[image]

I tried directly from database and able to see the results
[image]

Can somebody please help to save results with html tags from front end. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just decorate the Action on your Controller with [ValidateInput(false)]. But obviously make sure you do your own validation in the Controller logic.

Comment: I don't know why he or she cut my 2 points rather answering a question.

Comment: I resolved it by adding     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" requestValidationMode="2.0"/> in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I am adding ValidateInput(false)]. On the post action but on submit its not going action just display that error nothing else. If it goes to the controller then it would be easy to troubleshoot the error but no luck